# MongoDB query by document reference

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am building a search functionality based on an invoice Model. My search look like:

```
const { organization_id, start_date, end_date, search } = req;

const params = { organization_id };


  params['$or'] = [
          { invoice_nr: { $regex: '^' + search, $options: 'i' } },
          { reference: { $regex: '^' + search, $options: 'i' } }        ];
      }
      return this.model('Invoice').find({
        ...params, 
        created_at: {
          $gte: start_date,
          $lte: end_date
        }
      }).populate('patient_id', 'name last_name');
```

This works great and I can correctly query the document and find search by property invoice_nr or reference.

However I also want to query on the `patient_id` property by `name` or `last_name`. My problem is that `patient_id` is just a reference to another document.

Invoice Model:

```
 organization_id: { type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, required: true, ref: 'Organization' },
      invoice_nr: { type: String, required: true },
      reference: { type: String, required: true },
      patient_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Patient',
        required: true,
      },
```